# How to listen for change in variable inside a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a class called `Observers` to observe Firebase Storage Upload Tasks, but before observing the progress, it waits for PHPickerviewcontroller to upload the video. I have an instance variable in my class, `hasUploaded` so that I can know when I can start to change the progress bar, however, with the way it's set up, the block of code in the if statement will never be called. I know there is `didSet` but that doesn't help me in this case, because I need to listen for change *inside* the function. How do I do that?

```
func observeProgress(progressWheel: UIActivityIndicatorView, errorLabel: UILabel, progressView: UIProgressView, progressLabel: UILabel)
    {
        progressLabel.text = "Downloading from Device...Please Wait (1/2)"
        progressWheel.startAnimating()
        progressWheel.alpha = 1
        inProgress = true
        
        //RIGHT HERE - Wait for hasUploaded to == true
        if hasUploaded
        {
            progressWheel.alpha = 0
            
            self.taskReference!.observe(.progress)
            { (snapshot) in
                guard let progress = snapshot.progress?.fractionCompleted else { /**alert**/ return }
                progressView.progress = Float(progress)
                progressLabel.text = "\(round(100 * Float(progress)))% (2/2)"
                
                if progress == 1
                {
                    progressLabel.text = "Upload Successful!"
                    progressLabel.textColor = .black
                    progressView.progress = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get it entirely, why does *didSet* for hasUploaded not work. when hasUploaded has been set to true you call the observeProgress func. I think you can also work with ***Combine*** and use a ***@PassthroughSubject*** and work with publisher and subscriber (send and receive). Are you working with UIKit or SwiftUI.

Comment: @SebastianFox I need to call the function in a separate view controller, so having ```didSet``` in my class won't really help me here. I'm working with UIKit. I will try this @PassthroughSubject in my class.

Comment: It sounds as if you're imagining that your function code is magically going to pause and wait for something else to happen before proceeding! Only Combine or (easier) async/await can do that.

Comment: @matt I've edited my code above. How would I implement these concepts you had? (see comment)

Comment: @SebastianFox How would I implement that?

Comment: That's really too broad. There's _lots_ of information about this.

Comment: @matt I'm new to these concepts, so I don't really know how to incorporate them

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it again and maybe it is easier for you to use the NotificationCenter.

In the Model or ViewController add

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
```

and thenadjust the hasUploaded variable to

```
var hasUploaded = false {
    didSet {
        let statusChange = ["userInfo": ["hasUploaded": hasUploaded]]
        NotificationCenter.default
                    .post(name:
                            NSNotification.Name("com.user.hasUploaded"),
                     object: nil,
                     userInfo: statusChange)
    }
}
```

In the controller with the function observeProgress, also add

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
```

Add the following to the viewDidLoad() function

```
NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(self, selector:#selector(hasUploadedNotificationReceived(_:)),
                               name: NSNotification.Name ("com.user.hasUploaded"),
                               object: nil)
}
```

Finally create the function hasUploadedNotificationReceived() (which is called above whenever the notification will be received) to add the magic that should happen after the the change. For example:

```
@objc func hasUploadedNotificationReceived(_ notification: Notification){
    let notification = notification.userInfo?["userInfo"] as? [String: Bool] ?? [:]
    if (notification["hasUploaded"] as? Bool)! {
        observeProgress(...) {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Please read also the documentation to figure out what options you have and what you can add or modify.

Beside this implementation, I also can imagine that the a Delegate as well as Combine and as @matt mentioned async/await could help to achieve your desired behavior.